# EXIF details lost while posting image using Retrofit 2 with MultipartBody in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-camerax

We are capturing multiple images using CameraX and storing them on device and posting those images and text data using MultipartBody.Part and RequestBody. We found that we are not receiving EXIF details on server side. Is that an issue with Retrofit 2 Multipart? How we can get the images on server side without loosing its EXIF details?

Here is the code we are using

```
private lateinit var activityCaptureImageBinding: ActivityCaptureImageBinding

private var preview: Preview? = null
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
private var camera: Camera? = null
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private var metadata = ImageCapture.Metadata()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityCaptureImageBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@CaptureImageActivity, R.layout.activity_capture_image)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return
    }
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                metadata.apply {
                    setLocation(location)
                }
            }

    activityCaptureImageBinding.btnCaptureImage.setOnClickListener {
        takePhoto()
    }

    activityCaptureImageBinding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra(AppData.IMAGE_PATH, AppData.capturedCatsList)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()
    }

    outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            showLog(TAG, "Use case binding failed" + exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}


private fun takePhoto() {

    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

    showLog(TAG, "created file")

    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()

    imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
        override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
            showLog(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}")
        }

        override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
            showLog(TAG, "on image saved")
            val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
            AppData.capturedCatsList.add(savedUri.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Following is the Retrofit code

```
@Multipart
@POST("SimpleEncounterForm")
fun postCatImagesWithData(@Header("Cookie") cookie: String,
                          @Part catImages: List<MultipartBody.Part>,
                          @Part("datetime") dateTime: RequestBody,
                          @Part("lat") lat: RequestBody,
                          @Part("lon") lon: RequestBody,
                          @Part("locationID") locationId: RequestBody,
                          @Part("behavior") catBehaviour: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Method we are using to create MultipartBody.Part from Uri of stored images

```
@NonNull
private fun postFiles(fileUri: Uri): MultipartBody.Part {
    val file = FileUtils.getFile(this@DashboardActivity, fileUri)
    val fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.name, fileReqBody)
}
```

Convert Uri into File

```
public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null) {
        String path = getPath(context, uri);
        if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
            return new File(path);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `We found that we are not receiving EXIF details ` Details only or no exif header at all? Compare file sizes. Are less bytes received?

Comment: `file = FileUtils.getFile(this@DashboardActivity, fileUri)` What does that statement do?

Comment: `val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)` You could as well save photoFile.getAbsolutePath() and use that for Multipart instead of converting to uri and back.

Comment: @blackapps in getFile we do following


`public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: `Compare file sizes. Are less bytes received? ` I would rather you had informed about the sizes. That would have answered your question.